# Node js request external https url extreme slow

Tags: node.js, https

I use https.request method to invoke remote api, and use agentkeepalive,
however it still very slow.
The keep alive agent will take advantage of no agent used, however, it still very slow if first time invoke or socket has been closed.
what's the problem?

```
   var HttpsAgent = require('agentkeepalive').HttpsAgent;

   var keepaliveAgent = new HttpsAgent({
        maxSockets: 100,
        maxFreeSockets: 10,
        timeout: 60000,
        keepAliveTimeout: 30000 // free socket keepalive for 30 seconds 
   });

   var options = {
        host: WECHAT_HOST,
        path: WECHAT_PREPAY_URL,
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/xml",
            "Content-Length": requestXml.length
        },
        agent: keepaliveAgent
    };
    var request = require("https").request(options, function (res) {

        res.on("data", function (chunk) {
            ....
        });

        res.on("end", function () {
            ...
        });
    });

    request.on("error", function (err) {
        ...
    });
    //Logger.Write("Request ready");
    //console.log(requestXml.toString("utf-8"));
    request.write(requestXml);
    //Logger.Write("Data sent");
    request.end();//The problem is here, wait for about 12 seconds, if I invoke same request in firefox, the remote server response immediately.
```